# Python Spark - How to remove the duplicate element in set without the different ordering?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

By using the .fliter(func), i got the output below.

```
My output:
[((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3)), ((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3)), ((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))]
```

The output i need is only 3 coordinates.

```
My desired output:    
((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))
```

Any idea how to remove the duplicate set? i tested 'distinct.()' but it is not working due to the ordering of the element in the set is not the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort before then use distinct function

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3)), ((2, 1), (6, 3), (4, 2)), ((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))])
>>> for i in rdd.collect(): print(i)
... 
((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))
((2, 1), (6, 3), (4, 2))
((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))

>>> rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).distinct().collect()
[((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign your output as a list:

```
x= [((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3)), ((2, 1), (4,  2), (6, 3)), ((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))]
y = list(set(x))
print(y[0])
```

Than output is :
`((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))`

Answer (score 0):

distinct seems to work.  What I'm I missing?  What about the ordering "is not the same"?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3)), ((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3)), ((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))], ['tuple1', 'tuple2', 'tuple3'])

df.distinct().show()

+------+------+------+
|tuple1|tuple2|tuple3|
+------+------+------+
|[2, 1]|[4, 2]|[6, 3]|
+------+------+------+
```

If you mean that the order of the elements of tuples of tuples can be different then you can sort them as in the other answer.  I don't know a convenient way to create an array literal in PySpark so we'll convert the above DataFrame into a single column of array.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

mergedDf = df.select(F.array(df.tuple1, df.tuple2, df.tuple3).alias("merged"))
mergedDf.show()

+------------------------+
|merged                  |
+------------------------+
|[[2, 1], [4, 2], [6, 3]]|
|[[2, 1], [6, 3], [4, 2]]|
|[[4, 2], [2, 1], [6, 3]]|
+------------------------+
```

Now we can sort and distinct the array like

```
mergedDf.select(F.sort_array(mergedDf.merged).alias("sorted")).distinct().show(truncate=False)

+------------------------+
|sorted                  |
+------------------------+
|[[2, 1], [4, 2], [6, 3]]|
+------------------------+
```